# Converting an indexed image in uint32 to double

Tags: image, matlab, indexed-image

I read the following [in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2011b/toolbox/images/ref/im2double.html) of `im2double`

> **Class Support:**
>
> Intensity and truecolor images can be uint8, uint16, double, logical,
>   single**, or int16. Indexed images can be **uint8**, **uint16**, **double** or
>   **logical**. Binary input images must be logical. The output image is
>   double

I am working on a 64 bit machine (i.e. MATLAB uses **8 bytes** to represent variables of type double).  I have an indexed image of type **uint32** and I believe I should be able to convert it to type **double**, but `im2double` doesn't seem to support it, i.e. I get the following error:

> Error using im2double Expected input number 1, Image, to be one of
>   these types:
>
> double, logical, uint8, uint16, int16, single
>
> Instead its type was uint32.

So, how can I convert a matrix (an indexed image) of type `uint32` to `double`?

This is all on **MATLAB 2012a**

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f14-13543.html#brcu_xy) (some info [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/image.html#brnuhcm-11) as well):

> #### Indexed (Also known as a pseudocolor image)
>
> Array of class logical, uint8, uint16, single, or double whose pixel
>   values are direct indices into a colormap. The colormap is an m-by-3
>   array of class double.
>
> For single or double arrays, integer values range from [1, p]. For
>   logical, uint8, or uint16 arrays, values range from [0, p-1].

therefore MATLAB does not support indexed images of class uint32. I guess you'll have to do some sort of [color quantization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization).

Comment: Another good reference: [Displaying Bit-Mapped Images](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f2-1233.html)